# Polymer Nested Binding for Search

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, polymer-1.0

Below is my Element to Bind the Tree in Office->Team->"user" hierarchy. I need to perform Seach Over Users.

For Binding this tree, I took users array, performed some operations to get in the required hierarchy. For Search I am excluding the users not in users array and building the tree again.In the Initial input enter the search operation is working fine.when i press the next character, the users list are not excluding from the tree. But **generateTree** has the valid data when next character entered.

I guess the polymer is not doing its dirty checking until the array is empty.As the binding needs to be performed in the Users Array which is in Teams Array, That is in Offices Array. Help me out to resolve this issue

```
<template id="template" is="dom-repeat" items="{{generateTree}}" as="offices" id="user-level1-items">

            <paper-submenu id="user-level1"  SearchEnabled="{{search}}" class$="{{search}}">
                <paper-item class="menu-trigger menu-level-1">
                    <iron-icon class$="{{offices.icon}}" icon="{{offices.icon}}"></iron-icon>
                    <span>{{offices.name}}</span></paper-item>
                <paper-menu class="menu-content">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{offices.Teams}}" as="Teams" id="user-level2-items">

                        <paper-submenu id="user-level2"  opened="{{Teams.open}}">
                            <paper-item class="menu-trigger menu-level-2">
                                <iron-icon class$="{{Teams.icon}}" icon="{{Teams.icon}}"></iron-icon>
                                <span>{{Teams.name}}</span>
                            </paper-item>
                            <paper-menu class="menu-content" id="user-level3">
                                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{Teams.Users}}" as="Users">

                                    <paper-item " value$="{{Users._id}}"
                                    class="menu-level-3">
                                        <abc>{{Users.fullname}}</abc>
                                    </paper-item>

                                </template>
                            </paper-menu>
                        </paper-submenu>

                    </template>
                </paper-menu>
            </paper-submenu>

        </template>


Polymer({
    is: 'sa-org-tree-dynamic',


    properties: {
      level: {
        type: Number,
        value: 0
      }
    },

    inputData:function(){


        this.notifyPath('this.generateTree.teams.0.Users.*');



    }


    ready: function() {


    }

  });
```

**this.generatetree** i get from parent element.

Comment: Please show you element code

Comment: i have added the element code

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(generateTree))` .. works because the array push and splice is not done as per polymer standards